# Igraph R: Constraint calculation NA for some vertices for two combined graphs

Tags: r, graph, igraph

Using R and `igraph`, I have two graphs I have combined, then run `constraint()` on.  Constraint works on `g1` but when I add `g2`, `constraint()` returns `NA` for the new vertices added from `g2` and vertices next to these new vertices.

Here is example code that replicates my problem.  I obtain `g1` from a projection of a bipartite graph, as this reflects my data process.

My problem may be an issue with the union of the two graphs, but either way I try it (`g3 <- g1 + g2`  or `g3 <- graph.union(g1,  g2)`) the constraint calculation is bringing `NA`s.

```
set.seed(42)
g <- sample_bipartite(100, 10, type = c("gnp"), p=.03, directed = FALSE) 
gproj <- bipartite_projection(g, types=NULL, multiplicity = TRUE)
g1 <- gproj[[1]]
V(g1)$name <- 1:vcount(g1) #this gets their actual vertex id to show as label
V(g1)$name
components <- decompose.graph(g1)
largest <- which.max(sapply(components, vcount))
largest #this tells me which component is largest
lc <- components[[largest]]
lc
plot(lc)
cg1 <- constraint(lc)
cg1 #constraint for all connected vertices is calculated

#Create g2, some vertices in g1, some are new
rel <- data.frame( rel1 =
                     c(95), rel2 =
                     c(2000), stringsAsFactors = F) #create edgelist of g2, one vertex in lc, one vertex new
g2  <- graph.data.frame(rel, directed=FALSE)

#combine graphs and calculate constraint on combined graph
#g1 is used instead of lc because relationships in g2 may connect previously isolated vertices/components
g3 <- g1 + g2 
components1 <- decompose.graph(g3)
largest1 <- which.max(sapply(components1, vcount))
largest1 #this tells me the first component is largest
lc1 <- components1[[largest1]]
plot(lc1)
cg3 <- constraint(lc1)
cg3 #now constraint vertices close to 2000 is 'NA'
```

For further information, other igraph measures such as eigenvector centrality, degree, and bonpower do not experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Through some additional investigation, I have figured out a solution. The issue was `g1` had weights, while `g2` did not. With the weights removed, using this code (and using `g1a` down the line) `constraint` calculates for all vertices.

```
g1a <- remove.edge.attribute(g1, "weight")
```

Even better than it working for this toy example, this solution worked for my full, much larger, dataset.